# Beginner: what software to combine 2 videos of a dance show

Tags: video, audio, software-recommendation, sync

I would like to make a film of our dance show from 2 videos which were shot of it, keeping 1 audio track and the movement synched to the audio. Can anyone tell me what software can do this as easily as possible? I had a go a couple of years ago, spent many hours on it and completely failed! As far as I can remember the problem was that I couldn't line up the videos one above the other and in time with each other so that I could choose which bits I wanted to cut from one to the other and put them in the right place. I happen to have a reduction for corel video studio - can it do this, if not what can?

thanks very much

any suggestions on what the technical terms I need to do this are would be much appreciated to help me search the web

Comment: Do any of these [previous](http://avp.stackexchange.com/q/3018/2178) [questions](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/good-open-source-video-editors) help you? If not, what is missing from them?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a Non-Linear Video Editing packages or NLE.  Premiere and Final Cut Pro are two of the most popular, but they are also relatively pricy professional products.  There are also many cheaper and/or free options available such as Windows Movie Maker (Windows) or iMovie (Mac).  If you search for non-linear editing software or video editing software, you should find lots of possible options.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost no experience in video editing and I used kapwing (https://www.kapwing.com/tools). I found it to be very intuitive. It is free for videos below 7 minutes as output and below 250MB of input.

If you don't want to pay any money, you can trim the videos using kapwing and remerge them using the photos app (https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/merge-combine-videos-windows-10-built-in-photos-app/).